# Why does mysqli fetch() return empty results from longtext column?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, longtext

For some reason mysqli `$query -> fetch();` returns blank, the columns that are longtext in my mysql table?

Any ideas? I set the columns to `text`, it works fine. It also works fine on my WAMP server, but when I put it up to the production server it just returns blanks. Both systems are running php 5.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `$mysqli->query()` and `$result->fetch_object()`?

[Same problem?](http://www.develobert.info/2009/09/php-mysqli-bindresult-empty-longtext.html)

Comment: Ah yes! Same problem. Thanks for that.

Comment: Is there a solution to this that allows parameter binding?

Comment: Link is dead, what was the content?